# Модератор игнорирует просьбы прекратить обсуждение участника

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, чат

Модератор в многочисленных сообщениях в чате и на сайте обвиняет участника в троллинге, хотя участник с этим не согласен. Участник просит прекратить обсуждать его личность, но модератор продолжает это делать, причём пользуется модераторскими инструментами, чтобы заткнуть собеседника.

Должен ли модератор (впрочем, и любой другой участник) прислушиваться к просьбе прекратить обсуждение кого-то с многочисленными личными оценками, которые раздражают обсуждаемого участника, или он имеет на это полное право?

Comment: Ну хватит плодить одинаковые вопросы...

Comment: @Qwertiy После удаления всех деталей и конкретики это абсолютно разные вопросы. Объединять их в один было бы некорректно.

Answer (score 0):

По идее для этого предназначена система тревог на сообщениях. Абстрагируясь от ситуации - если вы считаете сообщения оскорбительными или иначе нарушающими правила сайта - поднимите флаг тревоги.

Не уверен, что настойчивое обсуждение участника вопреки его просьбам нарушает какие-то правила само по себе.

P.S. Вопрос - к кому на модерацию попадет тревога на сообщение модератора - этому же модератору или другому?

Comment: Если тревогу поставил не-модератор - ее видят все участники с правом модерирования (именно поэтому к нам в чат приходят модераторы с enSO). Если тревогу поставил модератор (любой) - она сразу же считается подтвержденной и приводит к временному бану участника.

Comment: То есть у модератора банхаммер есть, это ясно. А вот может ли модератор, на сообщение которого поставлена тревога ее "загасить"? Или все таки должен вмешаться третий человек (другой модератор). *В конце концов, модераторы тоже люди, и тожде подвержены эмоциям и ошибкам.*

Comment: Не знаю, не проверял. Предложил бы попробовать, но наверняка это вызовет приход англичан.

Comment: @PashaPash если бы англичан... скорее там индусы будут. Их просто больше.